# Using Postgres index operator in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given a table with the following schema:

```sql
create table json_data (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    default_object VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

For each of entity in the table I want to retrieve value of `data['first']['name']` field, or if it's null value of `data[json_data.default_object]['name']`, or if the latter is also null then return some default value. In "pure" SQL I can write the following code to satisfy my needs:

```sql
insert into
  json_data(
    id,
    default_object,
    data
  )
  values(
    0,
    'default',
    '{"first": {"name": "first_name_1"}, "default": {"name": "default_name_1"}}'
  ),
  (
    1,
    'default',
    '{"first": {}, "default": {"name": "default_name_2"}}'
  );

select
  id,
  coalesce(
    json_data.data -> 'first' ->> 'name',
    json_data.data -> json_data.default_object ->> 'name',
    'default_value'
  ) as value
from
  json_data;
```

I tried to "translate" the "model" above into an SQLAlchemy entity:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


Base = declarative_base()


class JsonObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'json_data'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    default_object = sa.Column(sa.String(10), nullable=False)
    data = sa.Column(postgresql.JSONB, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def name(self) -> str:
        obj = self.data.get('first')
        default_obj = self.data.get(self.default_object)
        return (obj.get('name') if obj else default_obj.get('name')) or default_obj.get('name')

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value: str):
        obj = self.data.setdefault('first', dict())
        obj['name'] = value

    @name.expression
    def name(self):
        return sa.func.coalesce(
            self.data[('first', 'name')].astext,
            self.data[(self.default_object, 'name')].astext,
            'default_value',
        )
```

But it seems that expression for the `name` hybrid property doesn't work as I expect. If I query entities by `name` property, like:

```py
query = session.query(JsonObject).filter(JsonObject.name == 'name')
```

The `query` is expanded by SQLAlchemy into a something like this:

```sql
SELECT json_data.id AS json_data_id, json_data.default_object AS json_data_default_object, json_data.data AS json_data_data 
FROM json_data 
WHERE coalesce((json_data.data #> %(data_1)s), (json_data.data #> %(data_2)s), %(coalesce_1)s) = %(coalesce_2)s
```

It uses path operator instead of index operator. What should I do to make SQLAlchemy create an expression such as I wrote in the beginning of the question?

Comment: Why does it matter if it uses path vs index? It looks like you're missing `.astext` from `self.data[('first', 'name')]`.

Comment: I forgot to add this, sorry. Anyway, as you can see SQLAlchemy tries to substitute column name with a some string value.

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution I found is quite straightforward. As SQLAlchemy documentation tells:

> Index operations return an expression object whose type defaults to JSON by default, so that further JSON-oriented instructions may be called upon the result type.

Therefore we can use "chained" python indexing operators. So the following code looks legit to me:

```py
class JsonObject(Base):
    # Almost the same stuff, except for the following:
    @name.expression
    def name(self):
        return sa.func.coalesce(
            self.data['first']['name'].astext,
            self.data[self.default_object]['name'].astext,
            'default_value',
        )
```